# Ableton Live Time-stretching Hotkey

Tags: software, ableton

In a YouTube-video, I saw someone stretching audio clips in ableton via mouse. He pulled on the top right corner to stretch the audiofile.

It seems like he pulled the audio file the same way you would trim a audio clip in ableton. So I think he pulled a hotkey while dragging the file to use time stretch instead of trimming.

I already read all the Hotkeys in the ableton manual and I could not find the desired one.

The code I watched is the "Recreate Prodigys Smack my Bitch up in Ableton Video"

Thank you and peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean stretching on 4:13?
He moves the little yellow markers in edit window (below the arrangement view) to stretch concrete part of sample between those markers. To create the yellow marker just double-click on the line above the waveform. Then take the marker and move right/left to stretch. To delete marker - double-click on him again (this would cancel your stretch edition).

Comment: Oh man i totally got it wrong. It seemed like he dragged the clip, but instead he typed in a new root bpm in the audio clip -> so the current project bpm cause the sample to pitch.